# TCL HTTP package problem with https connection

Tags: http, https, tcl

I am doing a simple bot that browse some pages and "read" the news in there. But in some pages, like "https://www.iprofesional.com" the connection does not work.

My code is as follows:

```
package require http
package require tls
package require tdom

            ::http::config -useragent "Mozilla/4.75 (X11; U; Linux 2.2.17; i586; Nav)"

            ::http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]   ;# "-tls1 1" is required since [POODLE]

if {[catch "::http::geturl $url" http] == 0} {
 set html  [::http::data $http]

            ::http::cleanup $http

            ::http::unregister https
}
```

If you run this code with that url you will see what is the problem.

Any idea how to make my code working with that url?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you unregistering the https handler? That's… unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code and i got the html content without problem.
Just added

```
set url "https://www.iprofesional.com"
```

after the packages line, and

```
puts $html
```

in the end of the if sentence.

I guess it's better if you paste your error.

Saludos,

Comment: My error is that the system is frozen after I call "set html  [::http::data $http]"

What version of http package are you using? Mine is 2.8.8 and is running under tcl 8.6

Comment: I tested the code exactly as you did... now my console is frozen when I try to execute the "puts $html". Maybe a bug in tcl?

Comment: http 2.8.8 tls 1.6.7.1 tdom 0.8.3 tcl 8.6 win7/32

Comment: Try with «puts [ ::http::code $http]» as the first line after the catch (in my case shows "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

Comment: I installed the latest version of tcl in my win7 machine, still the same problem. When I do what you suggest I get the same response.

Comment: http 2.8.9 tls 1.7.12 tdom 0.8.3

Comment: Hi, seems the problem is when I try to "see" the value of the variable, but in the case I pass the value of the variable to a function it works...

Seems to me like a bug in tcl. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: It is hard to follow the details of this answer to the point of reproducing anything claimed in here: _"Seems to me like a bug in tcl"_. @FranciscoPantano, can you post the full version details and a complete script that clearly demonstrates what you are claiming? For example, http in version 2.8.9 is clearly not coming with the "latest version" of Tcl. If you consider this a reproducible bug, you should help and open a ticket at [core.tcl.tk](https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/login?g=/tcl/tktnew&anon)

Answer (score 0):

The full code that freezes my console is:

```
package require http
package require tls
package require tdom

set url "https://www.iprofesional.com"

            ::http::config -useragent "Mozilla/4.75 (X11; U; Linux 2.2.17; i586; Nav)"

            ::http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]   ;# "-tls1 1" is required since [POODLE]

if {[catch "::http::geturl $url" http] == 0} {
 set html  [::http::data $http]

            ::http::cleanup $http

            ::http::unregister https

 puts $html
}
```

It freezes the console in the:

```
puts $html
```

I tried in an Acer Extensa 5230 with Windows XP SP3/32b and same laptop witn Windows 7 Professional Sp1/64b. Maybe a hardware related issue, don't know, but if I pass the html variable as an argument to a function it works without any probelm.

In windows XP I am running tcl/tk 8.6 and then I downloaded "ActiveTcl-8.6.6.8607-MSWin32-x86-403667.exe" and installed it in Windows 7 Sp1/64b partition and have the same issue.

I will try to test this problem in a different computer and will post my result.

Comment: No success... same issue with a new box with windows 7 and same tcl/tk 8.6 as my windows XP.